# Python Plotly: text does not appear in all sections of pie chart

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, plotly-python

I have the following code for plotting a pie chart using [Plotly Python](https://plotly.com/python/):

```py
fig = px.pie(df, names = 'Gender', color = 'Gender', color_discrete_map = {'Male': 'lightblue', 'Female': 'lightpink'})

fig.update_traces(text = df['Gender'].value_counts(), textinfo = 'label+percent+text')

fig.update_layout(title_text = "Gender distribution", title_x = 0.5)

fig.show()
```

Output:

[image: Gender distribution A Plotly bug]

The problem is that the `text` argument is shown only in the **Male** section, even though a `pd.Series` is passed.

Changing to, e.g., `text = ['A', 'B']` for testing purposes results in the same issue:

[image: Gender distribution B Plotly bug]

The output of `df['Gender'].value_counts()` is:

```
Male      831913
Female    144877
Name: Gender, dtype: int64
```

So I pretty much expected the value of 144877 to appear in the chart, since that happened to 831913. How can I fix this?

Comment: could you provide your dataframe that you used

Comment: try zooming in as well, I've seen text not display b/c of zoom problems before.

Comment: @AS11 It is from kaggle, avaliable at https://www.kaggle.com/vikasojha98/world-top-chess-players-august-2020. But I do not think it matters, since one could simply use a dataframe with a `Gender` column filled with random values.

Answer (score 1):

If the other answer didn't work, here is a different way of doing it. I couldn't get the colour settings to work for some reason though.

```
#simulating data

import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
rows = []
for i in range(85*5):
     rows.append(['Male'])
for i in range(15*5):
    rows.append(['Female'])

df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=["Gender"])


#plotting

fig = px.pie(pd.DataFrame(df['Gender'].value_counts()), 
                            values='Gender', 
                            names=['Male','Female'],
                            title='Gender Count',
                            color='Gender',
                            color_discrete_map={'Male':'lightcyan', 'Female':'cyan'}
                            )
fig.update_traces(textinfo='label+percent+value')
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This seems to work, but introduces this problem with the colors. I just replaced `textinfo = 'label+percent+text'` by `textinfo = 'label+percent+value'` and removed the `text` parameter and the problem was solved. I'll post this as an answer soon.

Answer (score 0):

Try 'value' instead of 'text' in this part

```
fig.update_traces(text = df['Gender'].value_counts(), textinfo = 'label+percent+value')
```

Comment: ValueError: Invalid property specified for object of type plotly.graph_objs.Pie: 'value'. Did you mean "values"?

However, `values` does not work either.